# Do base64 encoded binary data of the same type have the same headers?

Tags: encoding, header, base64, jpeg, file-type

All base64 strings have a header (according to Wikipedia it's 814 bytes). I was wondering whether these headers are the same for data of the same type, since I've noticed that when I encode JPEG images in base64, the first 500+ characters are the same.

Answer (score 7):

Not true. When base64 encoding a byte stream, the first three bytes of the byte stream get converted to the first four characters of the base64 encoded string. There's no headers.

See the [example section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) of the Wikipedia article on Base64, where the three ASCII encoded bytes for the string `Man` get encoded to four base64 characters `TWFu`.

So if two base64 encoded byte streams start with the same characters, the original byte streams must also have started with the same bytes. All JPEG files start with magic number bytes `FF D8`, possibly followed by a format string and image metadata before the actual image details follow. See [Magic number programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) on wikipedia

The headers mentioned on the wikipedia article on Base64 are MIME headers for email attachments.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more: base64 is simply a 1:1 translation of whatever bytestream came in. Every 3 bytes in the byte stream are converted into 4 characters in the base64 (except possibly for the last bytes, where some padding may be needed). 3 bytes in the incoming stream are 24 bits. base64 has this name because it uses 64 (actually, 66) ASCII characters. 64 characters can encode 6 bits. Thus, 4 characters can carry 24 bits of information, just as 3 bytes of binary data can. Except for the padding, that's all there is to base64.

Comment: @KevinKeane Thanks, have updated the first sentence from explaining what happens to the first byte to explaining what happens to the first three bytes. That's probably clearer.